# queryExecution.analyzed.stats.sizeInBytes always returns 9223372036854775807

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to check the size of the different tables we're generating in our data warehouse, so we can have an automatic way to calculate partition size in next runs.

In order to get the table size I'm getting the stats from dataframes in the following way:

```
val db = "database"
val table_name = "table_name"
val table_size_bytes = spark.read.table(s"$db.$table_name").queryExecution.analyzed.stats.sizeInBytes
```

This was working fine until I started running the same code on partitioned tables. Each time I ran it on a partitioned table I got the same value for `sizeInBytes`, which is the max allowed value for BigInt: 9223372036854775807.

Is this a bug in Spark or should I be running this in a different way for partitioned tables?

Answer (score 0):

It is showing default `sizeInByte` 8.0 EB.
Run this to update table stat in Hive Meta and then rerun above to see actual size:

```
spark.sql("ANALYZE table $db.$table_name compute STATISTICS NOSCAN")
```